# Parsing iOS device logs in Device Farm

Tags: ios, xctest, xcuitest, aws-device-farm

Device farm uploads the entire system log for XCTests and XCUITests - but I've found it incredibly difficult to parse as the download is in the form of a single line JSON object usually on the order of 10-20 mb.

Ideally, I'd be able to view the logs in the Console.app to do some nice filtering.

Has anyone found a solution for parsing these huge JSON log files?

Comment: Hello, are you using Custom Environments? Not sure if this meets all your needs, but you could probably update your yaml file to use xcpretty and use the junit or html report. If you send the output to $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR you should be able find the report in the Customer Artifacts zip after the test.

Link to xcpretty https://github.com/xcpretty/xcpretty

Comment: Thanks - that's a really cool tool and a great idea! But actually I'm looking to analyze the while system device logs - it looks like DF has a file system.log which contains what you'd normally see if you just opened Console.app for a connected device. This is the log I'd like to parse.